# Inserting Data into Local SQL Database through C# Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, sql, database, insert

I have a Local SQL Database.

My first table is Customers which stores:

```
customerID (Primary Key, Identity, Auto Incremented),
firstName,
lastName,
address,
email,
postcode,
phoneNumber.
```

My second table is Groups which stores:

```
groupID (Primary Key, Identity, Auto Incremented),
groupName.
```

I have a third table Customer_Groups to link those two tables which stores:

```
customerID (Foreign Key),
groupID(Foreign Key).
```

(this third table was used to solve the many to many relationship)

On my New Customer C# Windows Application Form there are Text Boxes to insert a:

```
first name,
last name,
address,
email,
postcode,
phone number,
group name.
```

On my submit button click event, how would I insert these values into those three SQL tables above including inserting the ID's into the Customer_Groups table? Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if I could be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

So i can show u so many help for SQL insert into local table [Help](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLS1QulWo1RIZrmdggzEKbhnfvCMHtT-sA)
There videos contains so many tricks
U want insert data in all tables at same time. So u have 3 tables then u have to write 3 method for inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Use PetaPoco, available using NuGet. It allows you to set up some simple DTOs, and when you write one into the DB, the DTO is updated with the new id, so you can use that (within a transaction) to write the next item.

It's a pretty simple micro-ORM